# Expected Values Indexed by Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

I am reading Durrett's Probability text (5th edition) and am trying to make rigorous sense of expressions such as $\mathbb{E}_{B_t}(X)$ and $\mathbb{P}_{B_t}(A)$, where $B_t$ is a Brownian Motion and $X$ is just some random variable.
I know that, for example, if $\mu$ is some measure, then $\mathbb{E}_{\mu}(X)= \int_{\Omega} X d\mu$. And if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\mathbb{E}_{x}(X)= \int_{\Omega} X d(\delta_x$), where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac measure. But how can I take this and write $\mathbb{E}_{B_t}(X)$ as an integral similar to the ones above?

Comment: $\mathsf{P}_x(\cdot)$ is the law of BM started at $x$. $\mathsf{E}_x$ is the expectation wrt $\mathsf{P}_x$.

Comment: @d.k.o. And what is $\mathbb{E}_{B_t}(X)$? How does one write this as an integral?

Comment: You can write it as $E_{B_t}(X) = E_x(X)|_{x = B_t}$.

Answer (score 0):

You know the meaning of $E_\mu$ for some measure $\mu$. $E_{X_t}$ ist must shorthand for $E_{P(X_t \in \cdot)}$